# Mac OS Django-admin startproject mysite receives syntax error

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to follow the tutorial on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/ and have made it to the step where you are supposed to run `django-admin startproject mysite` in the command line.

I have tried running the followings:

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

```
django-admin startproject.py mysite
```

```
$ django-admin startproject mysite
```

and

```
$ django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

and all of them receive

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

either with a `^` under the "t" in "startproject" or under the $ when I've tried that.

I've searched through about ten different posts trying to figure out how to proceed, and none of the answers provided have worked for me. They all continue to receive

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I would really appreciate any insight into why this is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: please post the exact error (copy and paste) when you run `django-admin startproject mysite`

Comment: also, the `$` in the tutorial [represents your command line prompt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/706186/difference-between-and-in-linux-environment).. It's not meant to be entered by you.

Answer (score 0):

What did you get as a response when you typed `python -m django --version` in terminal?

Given that you have django installed properly, `django-admin startproject *name of project*` is the correct syntax. (the first line you listed is correct).

Perhaps try to re-install django and try again. You can access the docs for installing [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/install/)